# change page title in all browser opened tabs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a system that can show notifications.

Each 14 seconds jquery will send a ajax request to check new messages based on last user activity (last time user opened a page).

If it has notifications I will change page title to `(1) page title`.
It is working ok, but just for 1 tab. **I'd like to show (1) in all opened tabs**.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = "0";

setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: '/js/alerts.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
       if( data.number > "0" ) {

    i = parseInt(i) + parseInt(data.number);

    document.title = document.title.replace(/\(\d+\)\s+/, "");
    document.title='('+i+')' + " " + document.title;

       }
      },
    });

 }, 14000);
});
```

this will check if has notifications, if it has, change page title.

php and mysql: (alerts.php)

```
$p_opendate = $_SESSION["page_open_date"]; // get last page open date
```

mysql

```
select count(c.user) as logs from chat c 
where c.message_to = 'user' and c.data > $p_opendate

if($num>0) // $number of new messages
$_SESSION["page_open_date"] = date ("ymdHis"); //update session
```

I'm using prepared statements in my real project.

This select will return the number of new messages after page opened (or after last data retrieved > 0).

**The problem is if user opened many browser tabs, I'd like to show (1) in title for all of them, not just one. Any ideas?**

this can be solved in php, mysql or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Is setInterval() function available only to to one single page?. If yes, make it a global function so that all opened pages can make the same call and update the title.

If it is a SPA, even user has opened many tabs, the setInterval() function will be available in all pages. So you no need to do anything else. The setInterval() function will trigger in all pages at the specified time.

Comment: thanks for your answer! yes, each page is count their own setInterval time... could you give me an example to make it global?

Comment: There are many ways to do it based on the application architecture.I am considering that there is a common js (like main.js or common.js) file which you include in all pages of your application.  If yes, place the piece of the code (setInterVal() function) in the common js file.